# Reading JSON file content using AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, json

I am trying to read and display publications and permissions section from JSON file below using angularjs. I am trying to display idno and title values from publications node and tou, resolution and terms values from permissions nodes. Bun when I try to run below code I am getting blank page.

Here is my HTML and Js code-

```
<div ng-controller="rFind">
    <p>The ID is {{pubs.idno}}</p>
    <p>The content title is {{pubs.title}}</p>
</div>

angular.module('demo',[])
.controller('rFind', function ($scope, $http) {
   $http.get('rfind.json').success(function (data) {
       $scope.pubs = data.publications;
    });
});
```

JSON File -

```
{
  "location": "US",
  "publications": [
    {
      "idno": "1360-0869",
      "workId": "122936490",
      "title": "INTERNATIONAL REVIEW OF LAW (1996- )",
      "permissions": [
        {
          "tou": "DIGITAL",
          "resolution": "GRANT",
          "terms": [
            {
              "code": "d0214dec",
              "description": "This journal title may publish some Open Access articles, which provide specific user rights for reuse."
            },
            {
              "code": "93bfc4ca",
              "description": "User may not include copies of portions of this Work in presentations shown to external audiences."
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "tou": "PRINT",
          "resolution": "GRANT",
          "terms": [
            {
              "code": "d0214dec",
              "description": "This journal title may publish some Open Access articles, which provide specific user rights for reuse."
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "tou": "REACTIVELY_SHARE",
          "resolution": "GRANT",
          "terms": [
            {
              "code": "d0214dec",
              "description": "This journal title may publish some Open Access articles, which provide specific user rights for reuse."
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "startYear": 1996,
      "customMessages": [ ],
      "publishers": [ "ROUTLEDGE" ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Not sure what's wrong with my code. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: any errors at the console?

Comment: I believe that you should do `data.data.publications`.

Comment: in version 1.6 success method deprecate use then method instead on success .

Comment: data.publications is an array, you're trying to access an object. If you look at my answer you can find a way around it.

Answer (score 1):

Publications is returning as an array, you need to do one of two things - fix the endpoint so it returns an object, or use the Array prototype `find` to grab the object, or grab the first index if it exists.  You're trying to reference the object when it is an array.

```
$scope.pubs = data.publications[0];

$scope.pubs = data.publications.find(record => record.idno === param.id);
```

Or you can do a ng-repeat on scope.pubs.

Comment: When I try to read using find using param.id I am getting an error --TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined.

Comment: With your response - it's really inefficient. You shouldn't really do all those ng-repeats - you should reconsider how you return that data.

Comment: @rapidfire09 - if you use .find on an Array, the prototype will return the first item matched.  You should really look at returning some things as an object if you are looking to only return one record

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. I will try to use find for publications. For permissions and term I would still have to use ng-repeat since there are also multiple permissions node within each publications and same applies to term node.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
angular.module('demo',[])
.controller('rFind', function ($scope, $http) {

$http.get('rfind.json').then(function (data) {
   $scope.pubs = data.data.publications;
    });
});
```

Comment: publications is an array and he's not looping it with ng-repeat to view the results so your answer isn't correct...  my answer addresses his issue correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for your responses. This is what finally worked for me -

*rf.js*

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('rFind', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {

    $http({
        method: "GET",
        url: "/js/rf.json"
    }).then(function mySuccess(response) {
        $scope.posts = response.data;
        $scope.pubs = response.data.publications;
    }, function myError(response) {
        $scope.myWelcome = response.statusText;
    });
}]);
```

*rf.htm*

```
<body ng-app='myApp'>
    <div ng-controller='rFind'>
            <p>ID: {{ posts.location }} </p>
            <div ng-repeat="pub in pubs">
                <p> idn: {{pub.idno}} - {{pub.title}}</p>
                <div ng-repeat="perm in pub.permissions">
                    <p> -> {{perm.tou}} : {{perm.resolution}} </p>
                    <div ng-repeat="trm in perm.terms">
                        <p>{{trm.description}}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>>
</body>
```